# Analysis of a high-pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-pass-filter

I'm doing some analysis of op-amp circuitry including the high-pass filter shown below.

I was given three questions to try further my understanding on the analysis of such system.

However, I am not quite sure where to start on this one. I have listed the three questions below, the derivation of the transfer function is where I'm currently stuck.

1. Derive a general expression for the transfer function of the filter
   shown.
2. Let R1 = 3.9 kΩ, R2 = 1.8 kΩ, and C = 0.33 μF. What is the filter frequency magnitude response at very low frequencies?
3. Calculate the frequency at which the magnitude response will be 3 dB lower than it is at high frequencies.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f10de9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_4
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{p}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{p}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, when we have an ideal opamp we know that \$\text{V}_x:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=\text{V}_2\$. So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{p}-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_x\$ and \$\text{V}_3\$:

- $$\text{V}_x=\frac{\text{V}_\text{p}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag5$$
- $$\text{V}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{p}\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag6$$

So, the transfer function is:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{V}_\text{p}}=\frac{1}{\text{V}_\text{p}}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_\text{p}\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag7$$

---

Now, applying this to your circuit we need to use (from now on I use the lowercase letters for the function in the 'complex' s-domain where I used [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)):

$$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag8$$

So, the transfer function will be:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_3\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{p}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag9$$

So, when we use the transformation \$\text{s}=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$), we get:

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2\right)}\tag{10}$$

The magnitude response can be found by solving for the absolute value of equation \$(10)\$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|&=\left|\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2\right)}\right|\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}_3\left(\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2\right)\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)\right|}{\displaystyle\left|\text{R}_3\right|\cdot\left|\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}_2\right|}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}\right)^2}}
\end{split}\tag{11}
\end{equation}

The magnitude response will be at a maximum when \$\omega\to\infty\$, at that point the response is:

$$\lim_{\omega\space\to\space\infty}\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\sqrt{\text{R}_2^2+\left(0\right)^2}}=\frac{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_3\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3}=1+\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3}\tag{12}$$

So, we can solve for the cutoff frequency as follows:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_3}\right)\space\Longrightarrow\space\omega=\frac{1}{\text{CR}_2}\tag{13}$$

Answer (score 0):

Brandon, the transfer function of the whole circuit is nothing else than the product of the passive C-R2 block multiplied with the gain of the non-inverting opamp stage. Just basics!